# How to print out a file line by line by using dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c

how is printing a file line by line done using malloc? Ideally, I want to allocate just enough space to hold a line in the file, print it, free it, and then repeat the process.

Please include code snippets, thank you!

This is what I have so far, but Valgrind is saying I have memory leaks.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    // char *line = NULL;
    char *line;

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    line = malloc(1);

    while (readline(fp, line)) {
        // printf("%s\n", line);
    }
    free(line);

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    return  0;
}

char *readline (FILE *fp, char *buffer) 
{
    char ch;
    int place = 0;
    size_t nchar = 1;

    ch = fgetc(fp);
    while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
    {
        nchar++;
        (buffer)[place] = ch;

        char *tmp = realloc (buffer, nchar);
        if (!tmp) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc failed, "
                            "returning partial buffer.\n");
            (buffer)[place] = 0;
            return buffer;
        }
        buffer = tmp;

        ch = fgetc(fp);
        place++;
    }
    (buffer)[place] = '\0'; /* nul-terminate */

    if (ch == EOF) {
        if (strlen(buffer) > 1) {
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
        }

        // free(buffer);
        buffer = NULL;
    } else {

        if (strlen(buffer) > 1) {
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, what have you failed on? People will be more willing to help if they see some effort.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment with instructions to do things a certain way? If not, what's the difference between "printing...line by line" and just "printing each character as you see it" until EOF. Since "\n" is a character, this will also print *lines* in a sense and it won't require any allocation of memory.

Comment: `malloc()` doesn't do printing.  How are you going to read lines?  [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html),
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), something else?  Do you have to worry about the information coming from a terminal (or FIFO or pipe or other source that is not a disk file)?

Comment: @Telemachus Nope, I just want the program to define a line (separated by newlines and the EOF), and later store them in a database. The printing is just a preliminary step

Comment: Valgrind is right — your code leaks.  You `malloc()` and save the pointer in `line`.  You pass that to `readline()` where it is reallocated — you correctly return the reallocated pointer, but ignore it in the calling code, so it leaks on every line.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  `EOF` doesn't fit in a `char`.

Comment: @plsplox Adding that line won't do anything. You need to store the result of `readline()` in a char pointer and `free()` it.

Comment: You need something more like: `while ((line = readline(fp, line)) != NULL) {
        free(line); line = NULL;
    }` (and probably keep the `free(line)` after the loop too).

Comment: You wouldn’t want to `realloc()` after reading every character, unless that’s an actual requirement (and an instructor probably doesn’t want to teach you to do that).  A classic approach is to read into the buffer until it’s full, and if you need more space, double its size.  Another optimization is to have a list of buffers, so you will never need to recopy the initial portion of the array.

Comment: Calling code fails to save the return value of  readline() `

Comment: @Davislor, perhaps you are mistaken; _You wouldn’t want to realloc() after reading every character_.  Why not?  The malloc() and realloc() functions in all modern standard libraries compinsate by allocating memory blocks that are generally larger than the requested size.  Subsequent resizing (with realloc) does not have to do anything, unless the underlying size is too small.

Comment: `readline()` is a well known system function.  It is a poor programming practice to use function names in your code that are the same as the C library function names.

Comment: the posted code fails to compile!  the first reason being the needed `#include` statements are missing.  Are you expecting us to guess what header files you actually included?

Comment: when a system function returns an error indication, use function: `perror()` as that will also output the reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the expected command line parameter was actually entered by the user.

Comment: if the command line parameter were 0 (stdin) then the call to `fopen()` would fail. so this line: `if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);` would never be reached.

Comment: there are three header files that contain the prototype for `readline()` `stdio.h`, `readlinee/readline.h` and 'readline/history.h`  All have the syntax: `char *readline( const char *prompt);`  Which does not match the function: `readline()` in the posted code, so the compiler will raise an error.

Comment: the function: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  The posted code will cause the compiler to raise a warning.

Comment: the posted code will raise a warning (that you should correct otherwise the compiler will make (incorrect) assumptions about the parameter types and return type for the function `readline()`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/******************************************************************************
** Read a line from specified stream into allocated memory.
**   (Caller is responsable to free the allocated memory).
**
** Parameters:
**    I__fp       File stream to read.
**    _O_line_A   Sets caller's pointer to the allocated memory containing the read line.
**                Caller's pointer is set to NULL if a blank line is encountered.
**    _O_eof      Sets caller's integer value as follows:
**                   0 = (FALSE) More lines available to read from file.
**                  -1 = (TRUE)  The end-0f-file was encountered while reading the line.
** Return values:
**    0           Call was successful.
**    ENOMEM      Could not allocate sufficient memory to read a line.
*/
int ReadLine(
      FILE  *I__fp,
      char **_O_line_A,
      int   *_O_eof       
      )
   {
   int    rCode      = 0;      /* Function return status.  0=SUCCESS. */
   char  *line_A     = NULL;   /* Pointer to allocated memory containing line read. */
   size_t lineLength = 0;      /* Length of the allocated line, not including the termination character. */
   int    eof        = 0;      /* End-of-file encountered flag. */

   for(;;)                     /* Loop forever. */
      {
      int ch;
      char *newmem;

      ch=fgetc(I__fp);         /* Read a single character from the stream. */
      if(EOF == ch)            /* If the value EOF was read... */
         {
         eof=(-1);             /* ...Set the end-of-file flag */
         break;                /* ...Break out of the for-loop */
         }

      if('\n' == ch)           /* If a new-line character was read... */
         break;                /* ...Break out of the for-loop */

      /* Allocate additional memory, sufficient to hold all characters so far read,
      **    plus one for the currently read character,
      **       plus one for the termination character.
      */
      newmem=realloc(line_A, lineLength + 1 + 1);
      if(!newmem)             /* Ensure that realloc() did not fail. */
         {
         rCode=ENOMEM;
         goto CLEANUP;
         }

      line_A = newmem;             /* Change to newly allocated memory. */
      line_A[lineLength++] = ch;   /* Append the newly read character to the allocated memory. */ 
      line_A[lineLength] = '\0';   /* Append a string termination character to the allocated memory. */
      };

//RESULTS:

   /* Set the caller's pointer to the allocated line read from the stream. */
   if(_O_line_A)        /* Allows the caller to pass in a NULL value for _O_line_A...   */
      {                 /* ...For example, if the content of the line is not wanted by the caller. */
      *_O_line_A = line_A;
      line_A = NULL;
      }

    /* Set the caller's eof flag. */
    if(_O_eof)          /* Allows the caller to pass in a NULL value for _O_eof... */
      *_O_eof = eof;    /* ...For example, if the caller doesn't need the eof value. */

CLEANUP:

   /* It is possible that the caller supplied a "NULL" value for _O_line_A.
   ** ...If so, line_A will not be NULL.\
   ** ...In that case, free line_A to eliminate potential memory leak.
   */
   if(line_A)
      free(line_A);

   return(rCode);
   }

/******************************************************************************
** Program start.
*/
int main(
      int    argc,
      char **argv)
   {
   int   rCode  = 0;   
   char *line_A = NULL;
   FILE *fp_A   = NULL;
   int   eof; 

   errno=0;   
   fp_A = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if(!fp_A)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "fopen(\"%s\") failed. errno: %d %s\n", argv[1], errno, strerror(errno));
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   rCode=ReadLine(fp_A, &line_A, &eof);         /* Read first line from stream. */
   while(!rCode)
      {
      printf("%s\n", line_A ? line_A : "");
      free(line_A);                            /* Free line memory when finished with it. (after printing, etc.) */
      if(eof)                                  /* Break out of the while-loop if this is the last line in the stream. */
         break;

      rCode=ReadLine(fp_A, &line_A, &eof);      /* Read next line from stream. */
      }

   if(rCode)
      fprintf(stderr, "ReadLine() reports: %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));

CLEANUP:

   if(fp_A && (fp_A != stdin))
      {
      errno=0;
      if(EOF == fclose(fp_A))
         fprintf(stderr, "fclose() failed.  errno: %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
      }

   return(rCode);
   }
```